# Why do electrons "move" to more positive atoms?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am currently reading about charges and electrical fields. And I'm trying to figure out why it is that an electron would move from a more negative atom to a more neutral / positive one.
The best I could come up with was thinking of the electrons as a "wave" of squishy balls that get more and more erratic the more balls you add to the wave, and on the "floor" of this base there are two sticky boxes that make movement harder. So when a large amount of them are gathered at one box, they make each other move, and that movement is enough to "escape" that stickyness and they fly off onto the vicinity of the other sticky box, where they end up. Apologies for the weird analogy, hopefully this can atleast help point out flaws in my understanding.

The hard part for me is getting why they "must" or simply "go" from a more negative environment to a more positive one. It doesn't make alot of sense for me atleast that they "just do" go there, but maybe it's because the explanation for that is too hard for me to get at this stage.

Thanks for taking the time to read / answer my question =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **ground state of an atom**, where the number of electrons is equal to the number of protons, is its fundamental equilibrium state. This is always given in a cluster of identical chemical elements (hydrogen, helium, ...). At a temperature close to 0 Kelvin and without electric or magnetic external influences, the electrons are firmly localized in the atom and their number is equal.

There are external influences on the atom. As the temperature rises, atoms begin to collide and electrons can lose their bond to "their" atom.

When different chemical elements interact, the atoms try to donate or acquire electrons in such a way that the number of their external electrons reaches a noble gas configuration. Our observations have shown that the first three noble gases are atoms with 2, plus 8 and plus 8 electrons again, and in these configurations they form very stable bonds between the protons in the nucleus and their electrons.

So there is a **stable ground state for any chemical bond** between two atoms. By the addition of atoms of other chemical elements and an energy supply from the outside, however, other chemical compounds are formed again, in which the acceptance or release of electrons between the atoms changes again. In electrochemistry, bonds are forced by applying electrical voltages and temporarily forcing electrons to leave atoms.

`why it is that an electron would move from a more negative atom to a more neutral / positive one.`
If the stable state is disturbed, as shown in the examples above, ions - i.e. atoms with an excess or shortage of electrons - can be formed. If the system is left to itself again or if energy is withdrawn from it, the electrons are recaptured. We know only - from our observations - that atoms try to reach the state of equal number of protons and electrons and that additionally in chemical compounds electrons are shifted to reach noble-grass configuration.

Comment: Are there physical relations or models which explain the urge these systems have to reach that equal state? I'm thinking about the last part of your post "we know only -from our observations ". Also thank you for the detailed answer, it got me to see it from a chemical standpoint as well! =)

Comment: Erade, to describe it in more detail requires an analysis of what electric and magnetic fields consist of. As long as this is not attempted, no model exists that can describe in detail the mechanism of attraction between charges. We can only state the fact of attraction. BTW, to this topic I have given some more answers on PSE.

Comment: Okay, thank you for bringing this to my attention. I'm going to sift through your profile later today and look at your other answers as well. Thank you for the help, have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly your analogy is not wrong but it is not correct as well. You need not to consider electrons as waves, just think of them as point charge. Now as far as I am able to understand the question I think the answer is very simple. Let's take a analogy here, say you have 4 chocolates and there is only 1 boy, So all chocolates belong to him. As the number of child increases the number of chocolate for each individual boy also decreases. Something same happens inside a atom. The nucleus holds the atom togeather. You may know about atomic radius so I will not waste any time in it. There is a quantity called Z effective which tells how many protons for 1 electron. Same as the analogy, If the number of electrons will increase, Z effective will decrease. Because of this the atomic radius of the atom will increase. The radius will increase additionally due to replusive force between electrons. Because the is radius increased, the outermost electrons become loosely bounded and if there is a positively charged atom(no. of protons>no. of electrons) it can pull those loosely bounded electrons. The reason it is able to pull them is because the atom has more Z effective than the atom holding the electrons loosely and so the electrons gets pulled by the other atom.(In most of the cases like these electron are mostly shared and forms covalent bonds in most of the cases). You can study inorganic chemistry of 11th class(I am from India so I dont know about your syllabus) for more insights about how this thing actually happens .